# Change the base of a number with exponent without logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I change the base of a number with exponent?

Express $$2^5 * 8^3 * 16^2$$ as a power of 4

My workings
$$2^5 * 8^3 * 16^2 = 2^5 * (2^3)^3 * (2^4)^2 = 2^{22}$$

Comment: $2^{22}=2^{2\cdot11}=(2^{2})^{11}=4^{11}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now remember that  $$ a^{mn}= (a^m)^n$$ can be read from right to left and vice versa.